# How to Authenticate and Authorize every WCF call?

Tags: wpf, wcf, wcf-security

I have WPF client consuming WCF service hosted in IIS. For authentication I am thinking of either certificate or user name authentication. Client calls couple of methods in WCF and passes some message.

1. For every call that comes to WCF, I
   want to authenticate the user.
2. To place message in db, I have to know who is the caller, what is their username and few other properties about the user. How to pass these info[may be a small object] on every call?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the recommended default behavior - each call to the WCF service gets a new instance of the service, and each call is authenticated and authorized.

Just make sure not to enable things like session mode in WCF, and don't go down the path of a WCF singleton.

Just keep a regular, standard "per-call" WCF service - no issue there.

If you're on a corporate LAN, you could also think about using Windows credentials for authentication (which is the default for `wsHttpBinding` and `netTcpBinding`).

There's a really extensive [WCF Security Guide](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/) which has tons of samples and how-to guides on how to set up certain scenarios of WCF security.

I would also recommend you check out [The Fundamentals of WCF Security](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=0611051) for a great intro to WCF and its security mechanisms.

A bit more advanced is the idea of [Declarate WCF Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163382.aspx) in which Juval Lowy introduces five security scenarios (that's a very worthy read!) and encapsulates them into security attributes to be applied to your service contract(s).

Comment: This is exactly what I have done and it works like a champ.  A recommendation here is to make sure that code that validates the user is super fast (because it gets called for every service call).  If the call to persistent storage is at all expensive for this, you might want to look at caching.

Comment: Thank you, I have been reading WCF security guide and I am going to read other two articles. You talked about per-call instance management, how do I send user info object on every call?

Comment: @iraSenthil: if you're using Windows credentials, you don't need to do anything at all. If you're using a certificate, you need to specify the certificate in the config (and do nothing in code). If you want to use separate username/password, you'd have to set those when opening the communication channel.